# A Project Works On One Computer But Not The Next?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception

My friend has an XML parsing example that I tried following, but it didn't work.  So, he simply put the project folder on his flashdrive, and I then imported it into Eclipse.  Strangely though, the app is **still** force closing.  Any ideas on why this could be occuring?  It's the **same** project!  If you want the code we're working with, it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147855/nullpointerexception-while-parsing-xml/7147902#7147902), in the question.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Crash log from LogCat:

```
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.example.testone.parsing/android.example.testone.parsing.LocalParsingAttemptNUMBERoneActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.example.testone.parsing.LocalParsingAttemptNUMBERoneActivity.onCreate(LocalParsingAttemptNUMBERoneActivity.java:59)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-22 10:37:35.279: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(482):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post the crash log from LogCat so we can see why it forced closed.

Comment: Have the namespaces changed at all?  Is it possible you're calling a different namespace that is in a different relative location now?

Comment: Everything is exactly the same - the namespace, the package name, even the project name.  Both the tutorial I followed and the exact project I imported from his flash drive don't work, but his project works on his computer.  I even tried cleaning the project, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are there any other exceptions in the log prior to the null pointer exception?  Specifically is there a "XML Pasing Excpetion"  (bad spelling is in the code).  I'm guessing your system for some reason can not access the URL and is failing to parse the XML.

Comment: Would you know why my system can't access the URL?  Our code is referencing the same URL.

Comment: Internet connectivity?  Proxy rules?  Are you able to access it from the device straight up outside the context of the app?

Comment: For one reason or another, its working today.  Something must have been going on yesterday... how strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one reason or another, the program is working the day after than the posted question's date.  My guess is something that went on with the internet connectivity.